# Multi-Select Tests

Tags: templating

I have a multi-select field that I need to test for any 'selected values'...the below always has a return even when no values are selected. How do I check this multi-select to ensure there are selected values to output?

Thanks in advance.

```
{% if entry.myMultiSelect|length %}
    <!-- Output HTML + option values -->
    {% for option in entry.myMultiSelect%}
        {{ option }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <!--Do something else -->               
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You on the latest version of Craft?  I just did a test using your exact code and it works exactly as you'd expect. Outputs the options if there were selections and skips it if there were none.

Comment: Hmm, so now that I think about it and re-look @ my code, think it is working correctly but my loops (and there are many) are not in the correct HTML blocks....thanks for your response.

Comment: When you get to the bottom of it, would you mind adding your solutions as an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was not related to the above code but more due to other loops in template. thanks for comments.